# Trigger on UPDATE of Specific Field

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm looking to create a trigger that adds the difference between DATE_BEGIN and DATE_END in a table as soon as DATE_END is added.

For example, say I have a table with the following columns

`ProjectName,Type,DATE_BEGIN,DATE_END,DATE_DIFF`

and I want DATE_DIFF to be automatically populated with the difference between DATE_BEGIN and DATE_END as soon as DATE_END is updated. So I'm sure I'm looking for a trigger with something being performed when an UPDATE occurs, but how do I track that specific column in this way?

I'm a bit new to Triggers, so I'm not sure where to start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a computed column instead?

Something like this:

```
alter table TableName drop column DATE_DIFF
alter table TableName add DATE_DIFF as (case when DATE_END is not null then datediff(day, DATE_BEGIN, DATE_END) else null end)
```

If you don't want the difference in days, choose something else in the call to the function `datediff()`.

Answer (score 1):

You validate:

You have to get DATE_END from INSERTED (NEW VALUE) and DELETED (OLD VALUE)
AND whenever they are different, You update your DATE_DIFF

```
IF ((SELECT DATE_END FROM INSERTED) <> (SELECT DATE_END FROM DELETED))
```

BEGIN
...

The docs: [Using the inserted and deleted Tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214435%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)